Why is the Jacobi equation not tensorial?
Let $\gamma: (-\epsilon,+\epsilon)\times I\to (M,g)$, $\gamma_s(t):=\gamma(s,t)$, be a family of curves in a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$. Denote $J:=\partial_s\gamma\rvert_{s=0}$ and $\gamma_s':=\partial_t\gamma_s$; the covariant derivative of the velocity along each curve $\gamma_s$ is notated $\nabla_{\gamma'_s}\gamma'_s$.
It is well known that, depending on the convention of the curvature tensor, one has $$\nabla_J\nabla_{\gamma'_0}\gamma'_0=\nabla_{\gamma'_0}\nabla_{\gamma'_0}J+R(J,\gamma_0')\gamma_0'$$ (If $\gamma_s$ were geodesics, this vanishes and $J$ is a Jacobi field.) I'm aware that there are many ways to arrive at this identity via calculation.
At first glance, the LHS ought to be tensorial in $J$ due to the properties of the connection: $\nabla_{fJ}X=f\nabla_JX$ for vector fields $X$ along variations $\gamma(\cdot,t)$. However, the RHS is manifestly not tensorial in $J$.
Is there a geometric explanation for why the naive expectation of the LHS tensoriality is false? Why should we expect $J$ to be differentiated?
